# stdout and stderr to terminal and file - problems with git client 2.26.2 - strange characters

Tags: linux, git, shell, stdout, stderr

I use the following command to get stdout and stderr in the terminal and in a file:

```bash
git svn rebase 2>&1 | tee test.out
```

But in case of changes in svn repository `2>&1` causes strange characters in `test.out`:

```
^M^[[KSuccessfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
^^^^^^
```

Hexdump with `hexdump -C test.out`:

```
0000000  0d 1b 5b 4b 53 75...
```

What is `0d 1b 5b 4b` and why does it appear in case of usage of `2>&1`? Without `2>&1` no such problems. Thx in advance.

Comment: I think those are ANSI terminal control codes to set the color of the output. When you say no problem without `2>&1` is the output "clean" but in a different color? Your terminal program is interpreting the codes in the non-redirected case, but not in the case where the output's directed to a file. Maybe the `svn` subcommand supports a `--no-color` option.

Comment: `0x0d` is carriage return... it's a control character that is used to make the cursor go back to the beginning of a line.... on a terminal you would not notice.... it would just be used to_overwrite_ a line that is in front of you.... but on a file... well, you get it there.

Comment: The `colcrt` tool allows you to remove screen control codes from a text file. This is a common beginner FAQ.

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks. Sorry, but I didn't know the source of the control characters. If I had known that it was the color settings of Git, then I could have searched accordingly.

Comment: No worries; we have all been there and it is genuinely hard to figure out how to search for something like this.